# npm run watch not working for laravel on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, laravel, npm, laravel-5.3

Here is the error i'm getting from cmd I tried look for a solution and not luck i didn't try it on OSX yet i might try that later

```
npm ERR! @ watch-poll: `npm run watch -- --watch-poll`
npm ERR! Exit status 4294963238
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch-poll script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run watch -- --watch-poll
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "watch-poll"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Yosef\Desktop\pos
npm ERR! node -v v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yosef\Desktop\pos\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you already started your webserver, the `ELIFECYCLE` error comes if you try to run the `npm` command again on another terminal session.

Make sure that you don't have any other instance running up.